how to enter adb password while installing apk in adb
I am trying to install an apk through ADB but after entering adb install e.apk the prompt asks for a password 15 times without allowing me to enter it ( I know what is the password)
here is what I see in the prompt
adb install b.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install b.apk: please input verify password: verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
verify password:verify failed!
v

I didn't find anything to help me and I expect to see successful install.

What Android device do you try to install the APK on (manufacturer, device model, Android version)? Normally adb doesn't need a "verify password", just the on-device popup adb dialog needs to be accepted to make adb work. May be the manufacturer had modified the on-device part of adb in a way that it now requires a special proprietary adb version on PC side to work correctly?
